# How to add z-index to vuetify checkbox?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a parent v-row with a v-checkbox and a div for text. So the moment I hover the parent,I add some background because of which my v-checkbox is not getting shown properly.

The below is my code:

```
   <v-row
      v-for="rsr in rsrList"
      :key="rsr.name"
      style="margin-bottom: 0px"
    >
    <v-row class="rsr-row">
    <v-checkbox
          style="rsr-row-check-box"
          :color="rsr.CalendarColor"
          v-model="rsr.isChecked"
        :checked="rsr.isChecked"
        @change="onChange($event,rsr)"
        dense
        hide-details class="shrink mr-0 mt-0"
    ></v-checkbox>
    <div class="rsr-name-box">
      <p style="cursor: pointer;">{{rsr.name}}</p>
    </div>
    </v-row>

    </v-row>
```

This is my style:

```
.rsr-name-box{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  }

.rsr-row:hover{
  background-color: blue;
}

.rsr-row:hover .rsr-name-box p{
  color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.rsr-row:hover{
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
```

}

This is the output before hover:

[image]

This is the output after hover:

[image]

Now when I hover, the v-checkbox is not getting shown properly.

I tried setting the z-index to classes like : *.v-input--selection-controls.v-input--dense .v-input--selection-controls__ripple* but it didn't work.

I tried the elevation for v-checkbox, but in vain.

Any inputs will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I add padding-left 8px to the checkbox component. May this help you.

```
<v-checkbox
  v-model="model"
  class="pl-2"
  :value="item"
  :label="item.name"
  :color="item.color"
></v-checkbox>
```